# Is there a way to reload a variable in JS without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to show some data on a Leaflet Map. Displaying the markers works like a charm, but now there is the next challenge. I need to update the marker positions every few seconds without reloading the entire page. For now I'm getting the marker values like this.

```
<html>
  <body>
  [...]
    <script type='text/javascript' src='maps/markers.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='maps/leaflet.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Content of markers.js:

```
var markers = [
        {
            "lastStateChange": "2020-07-19T19:51:52Z", 
            "lastLocationUpdate": "2020-07-20T08:12:18Z", 
            "lat": foo, 
            "lng": bar, 
            "batteryLevel": 41, 
            "id": "4628a429a"
        }, 
        {
            "lastStateChange": "2020-07-20T00:12:36Z",  
            "lastLocationUpdate": "2020-07-20T08:17:12Z",  
            "lat": fooo, 
            "lng": bar, 
            "batteryLevel": 100, 
            "id": "8d1374c35"
        }
];
```

The markers.js is updated every few seconds when there is a change in the dataset. Any suggestions how to update the content of the variable "markers" every few seconds without reloading the whole page?

Comment: you might need `ajax` to refresh contents in your page

Comment: It'd be interesting to know if `markers.js` is generated dynamically on the server (via PHP or something), frequency of updates, and how that data structure is transformed into a set of `L.Marker`s.

Comment: The `markers.js` is generated by a Pythonscript that calls a REST API every 10 seconds. The structure from the API is mostly what you see in `markers.js` I just cut a bit from the end and beginning and place the `var markers = [` at the beginning and a semecolon in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [leaflet-realtime library](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime). There is also [a demo](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-realtime/) in which the marker's location is updated every few seconds

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will try the leaflet-realtime library. Now Im using the worker method, but the leaflet-realtime library looks like the better choise for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, why don't you use `setInterval()` like:

```
setInterval(function(){ /*update markers*/ }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you have to do is to create a Web worker let us name it as synchronizer that would be called for a set time interval (say every 30 seconds your markers array value changes).

```
synchronizer = new Worker('markers.js');
```

**A web worker is a JavaScript that runs in the background, independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of the page.**

```
w = new Worker("markers.js");
w.onmessage = function(event){
  //Now we will have the response of the markers.js
};
```

You can read more about web workers
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers][1]